# Return GCS objects created between two dates

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

Is this the most efficient way in python of finding blob storage object created between two dates?

```
def objects_in_date_range(store, start_date, end_date):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(store)
    bucket_list = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket)
    for blob in bucket_list:
        name = blob.name
        created = blob.time_created
        # print(type(created), created)
        # print(type(start_date), start_date)
        if created >= start_date and created < end_date:
            yield name
    return
```

Comment: If `bucket_list` is sorted in `time_created` order you can `break` your `for` loop after `end_date`. I couldn't find information on In what order storage_client returns them. It is possible that sorting first and then running your loop can be faster if they are in random order. [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) will allow you to test which is faster.

Comment: Edit: sorting first will never be faster. You cannot really go faster than O(n) which you already have. There might be a small improvement if you use list comprehension or [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). You already have `bucket_list` in memory so I don't see a benefit of using `yield` here.

Comment: 1) The SDK uses a paging iterator. The iterator only contains about 100 items. 2) The time to perform the HTTP read of the object list will dominate any code performance improvements. 3) Do not make any assumptions on the list sort order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested 5 different methods for shuffled list.

TL:DR The most you can get is from removing variables `name = blob.name` and `created = blob.time_created`. Other than that you are as fast as it can be.

```
import random
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import List


@dataclass
class FakeBlob:
    name: str
    time_created: datetime


def func01(bucket_list: List[FakeBlob], start_date:datetime, end_date:datetime):
    for blob in bucket_list:
        name = blob.name
        created = blob.time_created
        if created >= start_date and created < end_date:
            yield name
    return


def func02(bucket_list: List[FakeBlob], start_date:datetime, end_date:datetime):
    for blob in bucket_list:
        name = blob.name
        created = blob.time_created
        if start_date <= created < end_date:
            yield name
    return


def func03(bucket_list: List[FakeBlob], start_date:datetime, end_date:datetime):
    for blob in bucket_list:
        if start_date <= blob.time_created < end_date:
            yield blob.name
    return


def func04(bucket_list: List[FakeBlob], start_date:datetime, end_date:datetime):
    return [blob.name for blob in bucket_list if start_date <= blob.time_created < end_date]


def func05(bucket_list: List[FakeBlob], start_date:datetime, end_date:datetime):
    for e in filter(lambda blob: start_date <= blob.time_created < end_date, bucket_list):
        yield e


now = datetime.utcnow()
fake_blob_list = []
for i in range(10000000):
    fake_blob_list.append(FakeBlob(name=f"foo{i}", time_created=now+timedelta(hours=i)))
random.shuffle(fake_blob_list)

for func in [func01, func02, func03, func04, func05]:
    start_time = time.time()
    [e for e in func(fake_blob_list, now+timedelta(hours=4000000), now+timedelta(hours=6000000))]
    print(f"{func.__name__} - {time.time() - start_time} seconds")
```

Try no 1 10000000 elemnts:

```
func01 - 3.8724558353424072 seconds
func02 - 3.9978816509246826 seconds
func03 - 3.567375421524048 seconds
func04 - 3.6989762783050537 seconds
func05 - 4.644185304641724 seconds
```

Try no 2 10000000 elements:

```
func01 - 3.899850606918335 seconds
func02 - 4.075393199920654 seconds
func03 - 3.6028025150299072 seconds
func04 - 3.732541084289551 seconds
func05 - 4.7251410484313965 seconds
```

Tests with a list of a smaller number of elements gave me similar results.

Comment: I did something wrong with `filter` as it is suspiciously slow.