# Fetching data from GCP cloud storage (avro files) based on last modified date

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, avro

I am in the process of fetching the latest data in Avro format from the GCP cloud storage to Bigquery. I have come across this [resource](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#loading_avro_data_into_a_new_table) that shows how to do it. Questions

1. Is it possible to get the latest modified Avro file ?
2. Are there metadata files from the GCP storage bucket that can help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to sort files to get the latest file from GCS bucket, you can change the condition based on the requirement.

```
gsutil ls -l gs://[bucket-name]/ | sort -k 2 | tail -n 2
```

To specifically get the latest `.avro` file from the GCS Bucket, you can consider this code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import re

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket-name')

files = bucket.list_blobs()    
fileList = [file.name for file in files if '.avro' in file.name]
     
latestFile = fileList[0]
latestTimeStamp = bucket.get_blob(fileList[0]).updated
            
for i in range(len(fileList)):
        
        timeStamp = bucket.get_blob(fileList[i]).updated
        
        if timeStamp > latestTimeStamp:
            latestFile = fileList[i]
            latestTimeStamp = timeStamp
    
print(latestFile)
```

To know more about Object Metadata you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata).

Comment: Thanks, @Prajan for this solution, I very much appreciate a quick question before I upvote or accept it, is it possible for me to use a timestamp e.g  `datetime.now()` to fetch the latest Avro instead of downloading everything and then check the latest as the solution suggest, I have a very huge data that I need to check the latest avro .Thank You !

Comment: Is your requirement to get files on the specific date or between two dates? Does this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70210978/return-gcs-objects-created-between-two-dates/70211645#70211645) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73528611/how-to-copy-all-the-files-created-on-a-specific-date-from-one-bucket-to-another/73531878#73531878) help?